# Portable Document Format to Use Adobe Acrobat (in Firefox)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

How can I change the [Portable Document Format to Use Adobe Acrobat (in Firefox)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLYbm.jpg)?

Can we modify this in firefox.cfg/ *.ini file or any other way, instead manually changing in Firefox Options -> Application -> Portable Document Format -> Use Adobe Acrobat (in Firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change this, go to about:preferences#applications, then find "Portable Document Format" then change it away from "Preview in Firefox" - here is a screenshot -

[image]